# Loop an array - Cannot invoke append

Tags: arrays, swift

This is the array's I have:

```
var tblID = [String]()
var tblUser = [String]()
var tblEmployee = [String]()
```

I am trying to append them to a csv file, like this:

```
    let fileName = "Tasks.csv"
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    var csvText = "ID,USER,EMPLOYEE\n"

    for content in [tblID, tblUser, tblEmployee] {
        csvText.append(content) // Error here
    }
```

But in the link `csvText.append(content)` I get error message: `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([String])'`

Any suggestions what I can do here?

Comment: Don't have parallel arrays – create a model type that has an `id`, `user` & `employee` property, and then have an array of that type, and iterate over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add an array of strings to a single string using the append method but that just takes a single string.

Assuming that tblID, tblUser & tblEmployee always contain the same number of items (otherwise this will crash) you can do this:

```
for content in [tblID, tblUser, tblEmployee] {
    for loop in 0..<tblID.count {
        csvText.append("\(tblID[loop]),\(tblUser[loop]),\(tblEmployee[loop]))\n")
    }
}
```

That will add a line will add a line consisting of comma separated ID, User, Employee with a new line at the end.

Edit:

To handle the situation where the array sizes do not match you can do this:

```
it tblID.count != tblUser.count || tblID.count != tblEmployee.count {
    print ("error")
} else {
    // Do the above here
}
```

The best you can do is either add the content of the arrays or print error.  You can't add some and then print error because if tblID had 5 entries and tblUser had 4 you don't know if the it's the first entry of tblUser that's missing or the last.

Comment: How can I create a check to avoid it to crash, and return a `print("error")` instead?

Comment: Edit my post to include printing ("error") if the array sizes don't match.

Comment: Thanks! Last question: Is it possible to only append each table if it has value? Lets say I have `tblID ` 1, 2 and 3. And if `tblUser ` has no value in ID 2, it does not append. If you understand.

Comment: The problem is how do you know which entry in tblID goes with which entry in tblUser.  For example if you had 3 entries in the tblID array and 2 in the tblUser array how do you know it's entries for 1 & 3 and not 1 & 2 or 2 & 3.  If you want to do something like that I would change the data representation to a struct or tuple.

Comment: Another problem comes up if the tblEmployee contains a , mark. Any ideas how to fix that, because it has another column named tblComment, and if the comment is like: this is a test it works fine, but it the comment is like this: this is a test, just testing it will add a new column after the , mark.. Any idea here?

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do with the results but a common way is to double quote the field like this: `csvText.append("\(tblID[loop]),\(tblUser[loop]),\"\(tblEmployee[loop])\"\n")`

Comment: Hm, it still adds a new column after the `,` sign. `tblEmplo‌​yee` contains 3 strings, the last string it something like `joe, nick & kim`, and after the `,` after joe, it adds as a new column...

Comment: It you add the \" correctly the last column should be "joe, nick & kim" having the double quotes.  Once you have done that then it will depend on what processes the file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without a data sample, but I think this is what you want to do:

```
// might want to verify that all three arrays are the same size before doing this
for i in 0..<tblID.length {
    csvText.append("\(tblID[i]),\(tblUser[i]),\(tblEmployee[i])\n")
}
```

Currently you're just trying to append the entire array to the string (which isn't even allowed), one after another, when I think you want to access the contents of each array.